# Remove All Traces of Renamed Account Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, user-accounts

The iMac I’m using now is a new one, but was set up using a Time Machine backup from my old iMac.

That computer I bought from a friend and instead of wiping it (had a lot of good programs on it) I used the standard tutorial to simply rename the user account.

I’ve never had any issues related to this up until now.

I just attempted to install [RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](https://rvm.io/) and when I did, it attempted to install it into the old account name `/Users/tai` and was a serious pain to undo.

Obviously somewhere, something is lingering in a file that references this old user account name.

Does anyone know where and how I would go about looking for this so I can resolve this to avoid any future problems?

Comment: No it was a pain to undo the mess, not to install or use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the old `tai` is an administrator/root account the best way to handle a case like this is to just create a new user with your username, grant that user administrator rights and then completely delete the old `tai` account.

A tool like [RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](https://rvm.io) is based on local user preferences and setup so creating a new user should suffice to clean up a mess like this.

Comment: The old user account doesn't exist. It was renamed using the Apple tutorial.

Comment: This rename was done, maybe 4 years ago. This installation of RVM is the first thing that's ever created a problem. Where would I find files related to `local user preferences` as you mentioned?

Comment: I installed RVM like so: `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` using my admin account. The tutorial was from the Apple website, it was 4 years ago, I have no idea how I would find that. I mentioned it because it was the `Apple recommended` way to change a user account, and not some random blog post on how to do it. I couldn't care less about RVM, it isn't even something I need, but it exposed this problem and that's the only reason I included it in the question. Thanks @JakeGould

Answer (score 0):

Renaming a user is not recommended by most real mac users.

It causes issues.

IF you change it, you need to:

```sh
chgrp -R for the user
chown -r for the user
```

Pray that you don't get permissions voodoo later in life (oops you just did, too late).

Your best move is to:

1. Enable root, then login as root.(stay in root for all the following 6 steps).
2. Go to > sys prefs > Users.
3. Create a new admin account (your new name, not a duplicate of your current name)
4. Open that new account folder, delete all existing folders and files.
5. Open the old admin account folder, move all existing files INTO the NEW account.
6. Open terminal and do the aforementioned chgrp and chown actions on that entire account folder. For example:

   ```sh
   chown -r newbob /Users/newbob
   chgrp -R staff /Users/newbob
   ```